# Android widget not working after reboot (Repeat)

Tags: java, android, android-widget

hello there in my widgets i am getting data from sharedpreference it works fine but when i reboot the device it is not working also the click events not working i have also tried the OnEnabled method previously suggested by some developers in previous questions but not working

here is what i have tried!

```
    private static final String REFRESH_CLICKED = "refreshWidget";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager1 = appWidgetManager;
    ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, ExtensiveWidgetProvider.class);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.extensive_widget);

    SharedPreferenceHandler sharedPreferenceHandler;
    sharedPreferenceHandler = new SharedPreferenceHandler(context);
    String result = sharedPreferenceHandler.getLongTermWeather();

    parseCurrentJson(result, appWidgetManager, watchWidget, remoteViews, context);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivWidgetRefresh,
            getPendingSelfIntent(context, REFRESH_CLICKED));

    appWidgetManager1.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    // Allow the network operation on main thread
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.extensive_widget);
    ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, ExtensiveWidgetProvider.class);


    SharedPreferenceHandler sharedPreferenceHandler;
    sharedPreferenceHandler = new SharedPreferenceHandler(context);
    String result = sharedPreferenceHandler.getLongTermWeather();

    if (REFRESH_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //your onClick action is here
        Log.i("****", "clickd");
        String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        parseCurrentJson(result, appWidgetManager, watchWidget, remoteViews, context);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetUpdateTime, "Last Update: " + currentTime);
    }
    // Apply the changes
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.extensive_widget);
    ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, ExtensiveWidgetProvider.class);

    SharedPreferenceHandler sharedPreferenceHandler;
    sharedPreferenceHandler = new SharedPreferenceHandler(context);
    String result = sharedPreferenceHandler.getLongTermWeather();

    String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetUpdateTime, "Last Update: " + currentTime);
```

//        parseCurrentJson(result, appWidgetManager, watchWidget, remoteViews, context);

```
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivWidgetRefresh,
            getPendingSelfIntent(context, REFRESH_CLICKED));

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

}


// Catch the click on widget views
protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try clean and rebuild to make it work or upgrade android studio

Comment: Lol i have tried it and my Android studio is upgraded

Comment: i have also tried invalidate cache and restart but still same ... you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

The onUpdate does not get called on boot.
simply add

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1" >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

inside your `<receive>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file.